# Extend my plugin settings with hooks

Tags: plugins, settings-api

I need to add a new options to my settings, the new filed shown in settings page but not saved.

My add_settings_field callback:

```
  public function field_option_callback()
    {
        ?>
        <p>
            <input type='checkbox' name='my_options[imgs][]' <?php checked( in_array( 'thumbnail', $imgs ), 1 ); ?> value='thumbnail'>
            <label><?php _e('Thumbnail','do'); ?></label>
        </p>
        <?php
        $html = "";
       echo apply_filters( 'after_options_callback', $html );
    }
```

How I can add more fields and settings to my plugin using hooks?

EDIT: It works if I remove sanitize_callback from register_setting and use add_filter in same plugin file

Answer (score -1):

You can use `do_action( 'add_more_field', $post->ID, $post );` to extend fields

For more : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: I did that already, but new fields not saved.

Comment: I think you've just added the input fields like shown above. but didn't save it. 
Hopefully, keeping all input name under "my_options" will solve the problem 

For example : if you want to add "subtitle" then input name should be my_options[subtitle]

Comment: yes it have same name, it work if I put the code in same plugin file

Comment: Is the action name add_more_field correct? I can't find that one.